# How to create database and table in command prompt sqlite in android

Tags: android

Can anybody tell me how to create a database and table in adb shell command prompt in android? How do I access the table in Java code? Give an example.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use Sqlite3 command to connect to database from adb shell. Find example [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html#sqlite) This will open an sql prompt where you can execute standard commands supported. Another link which explains creating a database, creating table and viewing its contents all from command prompt (adb shell) is [here](http://vinnysoft.blogspot.com/2009/09/creating-databases-from-sqlite-shell.html).

For accessing Table check [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/index.html)..Download the Zip file..